# Delete elements below some element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've next code:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#delete-button').click(function () {
        deleteElementsBelow('#parent-container', 'element-2');
    });
    
    function deleteElementsBelow(parentContainerSelector, deleteBelowSelector) {
        var deleteOthers = false;
        $(parentContainerSelector).children().each(function () {
            var $elem = $(this);

            if (deleteOthers) {
                $elem.remove();
            } else if ($elem.hasClass(deleteBelowSelector)) {
                deleteOthers = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#parent-container div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#parent-container div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-container">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"></div>
    <div class="element-3"></div>
    <div class="element-4"></div>
    <button id="delete-button" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do action `deleteElementsBelow` by native jQuery API?

Comment: below means next? use `.next()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `$(parentContainerSelector + " ." +deleteBelowSelector).nextAll("div").remove()` to remove all `div` after the target element.

This will remove `divs` with class `element-3` and `element-4`

```js
$(function () {
    $('#delete-button').click(function () {
        deleteElementsBelow('#parent-container', 'element-2');
    });
    
    function deleteElementsBelow(parentContainerSelector, deleteBelowSelector) {
        var deleteOthers = false;
        $(parentContainerSelector + " ." +deleteBelowSelector).nextAll("div").remove()
    }
});
```

```css
#parent-container div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#parent-container div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-container">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"></div>
    <div class="element-3"></div>
    <div class="element-4"></div>
    <button id="delete-button" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's more convenient.

I will really use `.nextAll(.remove()` because I need to remove all elements